# Using if/else statements in setters

Tags: constructor, field, setter, getter, modifier

in my UML it is telling me to not let the field update if the value is negative

```
public void setCurrentBalance(double currentBalance)
{
    if (currentBalance <= 0)
        this.currentBalance = currentBalance;
    else
        this.currentBalance = currentBalance;
}
```

Does this look correct if my constructor looks like:

```
    setAccountNumber(accountNumber);
    setOwnerFirstName(ownerFirstName);
    setOwnerLastName(ownerLastName);
    setCurrentBalance(currentBalance);
    setMinimumBalanceRequired(minimumBalanceRequired);
```

Comment: Your if statement is currently useless... if the value is 0 or below you update the value, otherwise you do exactly the same thing...

Comment: Just realized it needs to be => lol, thanks, but otherwise does it look good, I have been hung up on this and I cant compile it yet because I still have some other open ends.

Comment: It doesn't really matter which way it faces when you have the same action in both the if and else branches...

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: oh I know what you mean, I need the if statement to set it to 0, if it is negative. correct?